# How can I get MariaDB to resume action?

Tags: debian, services, mariadb, wordpress

I was working on my Wordpress site, and to get a non-database, HTML version suitable for my  [datamine](https://github.com/JonathanHayward/datamine), such as is running correctly at https://orthodoxchurchfathers.com and https://searchgkchesterton.com, ran a `wget -r --no-check-certificate https://cjshayward.com` to create a partial version of the site with pages as individual files insteaad of database-dependent.

When I went to see if it is working, it gave a Wordpress error page that says "Error establishing a database connection." A little poking and it turned up that Mariadb's server was not running, and this not running persisted after a reboot.

From the command line:

```
# service mysqld start
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@technoluddites:~/wordpress/wp-content# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.22 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-11-15 12:44:41 CST; 15s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 5287 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5288 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5290 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_STA
  Process: 5342 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5342 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Nov 15 12:44:34 technoluddites.org systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.22 database server...
Nov 15 12:44:35 technoluddites.org mysqld[5342]: 2022-11-15 12:44:35 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 5342 ...
Nov 15 12:44:41 technoluddites.org systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 15 12:44:41 technoluddites.org systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 15 12:44:41 technoluddites.org systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.22 database server.
root@technoluddites:~/wordpress/wp-content# journalctl -xe
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5479]: connect to partcafe.com[162.210.199.85]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5475]: connect to xrumer.app[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5482]: connect to shavers.hair[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5487]: connect to hard.raytoy.com[23.82.12.35]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5476]: connect to hard.raytoy.com[37.48.65.136]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5483]: connect to makeup.blue[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5491]: connect to free.pieurl.com[81.171.28.46]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5485]: connect to partcafe.com[23.82.12.37]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5484]: connect to hard.raytoy.com[37.48.65.136]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5480]: connect to xrummer.com[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5474]: connect to koobiyocabs.com[99.83.154.118]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5489]: connect to partcafe.com[185.107.56.54]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5497]: connect to customketodiet.tips[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5377]: connect to customketodiet.kitchen[99.83.154.118]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5499]: connect to partcafe.com[185.107.56.54]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5372]: connect to xrummer.com[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5486]: connect to 1000welectricscooter.com[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5504]: connect to e.razore100.fans[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5481]: connect to chestpain.one[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5502]: connect to thailandmovers.com[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5492]: connect to linkbuildingtools.club[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5505]: connect to c.bangkokremovals.com[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5506]: connect to a.roofvent.xyz[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5376]: connect to xrummer.com[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5494]: connect to c.razore100.fans[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5496]: connect to e.shavers.hair[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5495]: connect to d.japantravel.network[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5383]: connect to customketodiet.kitchen[99.83.154.118]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5501]: connect to a.singaporetravel.network[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5369]: connect to a.southafricatravel.club[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5503]: connect to f.babyteeth.club[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5507]: connect to dnatest.news[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5498]: connect to i.most-wanted-stuff.com[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:15 technoluddites.org postfix/smtp[5381]: connect to a.australia-travel.news[64.44.23.135]:25: Connection timed out
Nov 15 12:45:17 technoluddites.org CRON[5523]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 15 12:45:20 technoluddites.org sshd[5666]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=212.34.245.65  user=root
Nov 15 12:45:22 technoluddites.org sshd[5666]: Failed password for root from 212.34.245.65 port 43956 ssh2
Nov 15 12:45:23 technoluddites.org sshd[5666]: Received disconnect from 212.34.245.65 port 43956:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Nov 15 12:45:23 technoluddites.org sshd[5666]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 212.34.245.65 port 43956 [preauth]
Nov 15 12:45:25 technoluddites.org sshd[5668]: Connection closed by 125.119.1.16 port 21724 [preauth]
```

The searching I've done so far has turned up results saying "Clear the data directory if you don't have anything worth mentioning in the data directory," and maybe to reinstall MariaDB, but have not yet offered any advice on what to do if I don't want to lose something that in fact is worth keeping to me in the database.

I've put a little duct tape on my site by tarring up the Wordpress installation directory and then doing:

```
# for x in `find . -name \*.html`; do cp --parents $x ~/wordpress; echo $x; done
```

from the snapshot created by wget, and after renaming ~/wordpress/index.php, it serves the site more or less as before. So, the symptom is at least partly suppressed by now, but in a way that does nothing to address the problem.

A next thought that I have is to move out, instead of deleting, database files, see if I can get it working, and then see if I can pin down what stops MariaDB from starting.

I have previously run a recursive wget without reported issue.

How did attempting a wget take down, or trigger taking down, the database?

What can I do to get MariaDB working without discarding the databases?

Are there any approaches besides systematically moving out databases and seeing whether MariaDB will start?

Would it make sense to migrate to MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find out **why** MariaDB isn't starting. Check out this page of [troubleshooting advice on the MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/) website.

It says:

> The reason for the failure will almost certainly be written in the error log and, if you are starting MariaDB manually, to the console. By default, the error log is named host-name.err and is written to the data directory.
> Common Locations:
>
> /var/log/
>
> /var/log/mysql

If the logs don't show enough information, try [increasing the logging verbosity](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_warnings) and attempt to start MariaDB again.